# How to clear $this to insert more records in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

With CI, I want to insert one record in User table and one in Post table. Below is a brief of my code (two tables will have multiple columns, and I just use one as example).

```
$this->username=$user;
$this->db->insert('User',$this);
$this->title='my first post';
$this->db->insert('Post', $this);
```

However, the second insert will be something like "insert into Post (user, title) values ('$user', 'my first post'). And an error is reported that unknown column user in Post.

How can I clear the members in $this before inserting the next records (in another table)?

Comment: you can just `unset` the part you don't want

Comment: Is there any managed approach? The columns could be many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happening becouse of

```
$this->username=$user;
```

You probably need to use

```
$this->db->insert('Post', $this->title);
```

And before you insert, set in title anything you want, but not

```
$this->db->insert('Post', $this);
```

However if you still want to work with an object, more information how to do this properly you can find here, http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert

Comment: Well, my stupidity... I got example code of using $this as an object and of course I can use different object variables...

Answer (score 1):

CI used array as the second argument in the `insert` method. The index will be the column name and the value referred by the index will be the value to be inserted. What you did was you just keep adding into the `$this` array.

When you first add username the array will look like this(neglecting the db) inside `$this` :

```
array( 'username' => $user );
```

When you add the title, it will become like this:

```
array( 'username' => $user, 'title' => 'my first post');
```

See how the previous entry still in there.

You can just `unset($this->username);`

or you can use another variable to hold your data instead of `$this`. Example:

```
$data = array('username' => $user);
$this->db->insert('User',$data);
$data = array('title' => 'my first post');
$this->db->insert('Post',$data);
```

And you can insert into two columns like this:

```
$data = array('username' => $user, 'description' => 'i am sleepy');
$this->db->insert('User',$data);
```

Hope my answer can help you.